# Using top classification layer to pre trained Inception V3 layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to DL and need some help with the Inception V3 model. As we know that by default pre-trained Keras model of inception v3 model uses weights from imagenet and gives output for 1000 classes. Now I want to add the output layer with 100 classes for the COIL dataset which as per my knowledge is not available for Keras. So how could I add new weights or if possible how could I change the classes for imagenet from 1000 to 100?

Also is there a possibility to add mnist dataset to the inceptionV3 network?

Answer (score 1):

To set InceptionV4 for 100 classes execute the code below. Set `include_top=False` removes the top layer of the model. Setting `pooling='max'` provides a global max pooling layer as the model output. This can be fed directly into dense layer for classification.

```
img_shape=(height, width) # specify the desired image dimension to use
model=tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3( include_top=False,  weights="imagenet",
     input_shape=img_shape, pooling='max')
x=model.layers[-1].output
predictions=Dense (100, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=predictions)    
model.compile(Adam(lr=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```